# Using Excel to add 2 cells gives wrong answer

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm trying to add 2 cells together using =SUM(L10*D3). L10 contains the number 280, D3 contains currency 0.04171, even if I change this to number, it still shows £11.67 instead of £11.68, any reason why?

Answer (score 0):

=SUM takes the count of many cells. Then the * means multiply.

Basically what you are doing is multiplying the two cells and =sum will then wrongly round it down.

A simple =L10*D3 should be suffice.

If you need to actually round it, use =round(L10*D3,2)

Answer (score 0):

This is not how you should use the SUM function.
The purpose of the SUM function is making the sum of different cells, not to make a multiplication.

If you just want the conversion, you should use `=L10*D3`, that would be enough.

Concerning the result, `0.04171*280=11.6788`, if you want Excel to show 11.68£, you should change the cell format to monetary with two digits.

That should work.